# Adding weblogic server to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have installed weblogic 10.3.5 in my machine. I have checked out my project and now trying to add this to the app server. I went to server folder, right clicked

```
Server - > Select Server under wizard - > select server -> next -> i see a list of servers.
```

When i click oracle under the New Server my oracle weblogic is not listed. I can just see Oracle OC4J Standalone Server 10.1.3 and 10.1.3n. What should i do so my server is listed and i select them?

Answer (score 5):

In the screen where you see OC4J, etc, you must click `Download additional server adapters`.
Wait for the list to load and then select "Oracle Weblogic Server Tools" from the list and click "Next".
Make sure you go through the licenses, agree with them and then accept the agreement and click "Next" (applying default values all the way through the end of the wizard, if applicable).
Now, right-click again your "Servers" panel, and click "New->Server" again. Scroll down to the "Oracle" folder and select the correct version of your Weblogic installation (probably "Oracle WebLogic Server 10gR3", according to your question). Set the "Weblogic home" with the home folder of your Weblogic instance (the default is C:\Oracle\Middleware[wlServer_VERSION_#] on Windows operating system).
On the next screen, leave every configuration at its default, but be sure to select your Domain directory. Click "Finish".
Your Weblogic runtime should now be available for selection.